# jQuery filtering by data attribute via two select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble filtering resulting div's with jQuery via two different inputs. Users can decide to filter by **office**, **specialty** or **both office and specialty**. The filtering is set from data attributes on the div that correspond to the select inputs values.

```
<div>
  <label for="officeSearch">Search by office:</label>
  <select name="Office Search" id="officeSearch">
    <option value="all"></option>
    <option value="communication">Communication</option>
    <option value="internal medicine">Internal Medicine</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="specialtySearch">Search by specialty:</label>
  <select name="Specialty Search" id="specialtySearch">
    <option value="all"></option>
    <option value="Bone Cancer">Bone Cancer</option>
    <option value="Breast Cancer">Breast Cancer</option>
    <option value="Oral Cancer">Oral Cancer</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="module-sm profile" data-office="communication" data-specialty="Oral Cancer">
  <p>Person A</p>
</div>
<div class="module-sm profile" data-office="communication" data-specialty="Breast Cancer">
  <p>Person B</p>
</div>
<div class="module-sm profile" data-office="internal medicine" data-specialty="Bone Cancer">
  <p>Person C</p>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using that fires on change of the selects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#officeSearch").on('change', function(){
    var selectedOffice = $('#officeSearch').val();
    var selectedSpecialty = $('#specialtySearch').val();
    var person = $('#filterList .profile').not('.out');
    var allPersons = $('#filterList .profile');
    var allPersonsOffice = $('#filterList .profile').data('office');
    var allPersonsOut = $('#filterList .profile.out');

    var office = $('.profile[data-office="' + selectedOffice +'"]');

    alert(''+ selectedOffice + ' ' + selectedSpecialty +'');

    if (selectedOffice == 'all' && selectedSpecialty == 'all'){
        $(allPersons).removeClass('out').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        $(person).not(office).addClass('out').fadeOut(500);
        office.removeClass('out').fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
  $("#specialtySearch").on('change', function(){
    var selectedOffice = $('#officeSearch').val();
    var selectedSpecialty = $('#specialtySearch').val();
    var person = $('#filterList .profile').not('.out');
    var allPersons = $('#filterList .profile');
    var allPersonsOffice = $('#filterList .profile').data('office');
    var allPersonsOut = $('#filterList .profile.out');

    var specialty = $('.profile[data-specialty="' + selectedSpecialty +'"]');

    alert(''+ selectedOffice + ' ' + selectedSpecialty +'');

    if (selectedOffice == 'all' && selectedSpecialty == 'all'){
        $(allPersons).removeClass('out').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        $(person).not(specialty).addClass('out').fadeOut(500);
        specialty.removeClass('out').fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
});
```

If it helps, I've made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/samyerkes/pen/Inaht) to demonstrate what I'm trying to do and where I'm at so far.

I've done some searching and have been scratching my head on how to get this working for weeks. Any help making this code more concise or examples to how others have solved this problem are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do not actually state what is wrong with your current code anywhere :)

Comment: Sorry, it's such a confusing problem it's hard to put into words... currently applying one select filters out correctly, but when you apply the second filter it applies it to all "people" and not just the people that the first filter applied to. I hope that makes sense! :-)

Comment: it's even more confusing (for everyone else) if you don't put it into words :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Very true, I've edited the comment above. Sorry I'm very new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Call a single update from either selection changing.
2. Create a filter based on the selections (appended).
3. Hide the ones not in the matches
4. show the matches.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2u7NY/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var onChange = function () {

        var selectedOffice = $('#officeSearch').val();
        var selectedSpecialty = $('#specialtySearch').val();
        var filter = "#filterList .profile";
        var allPersons = $(filter);
        if (selectedOffice != "all")
        {
            filter += '[data-office="' + selectedOffice + '"]'
        }
        if (selectedSpecialty != "all")
        {
            filter += '[data-specialty="' + selectedSpecialty + '"]'
        }
        var $matching = allPersons.filter(filter);
        $(allPersons).not($matching).removeClass('out').fadeOut(500);
        $matching.removeClass('out').fadeIn(500);        
    }

    $("#officeSearch, #specialtySearch").on('change', onChange );
});
```

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2u7NY/2/

The filter can be made slightly more efficient as "#filterList .profile" is not needed to filter `allPersons` based on attributes.

I also removed the function variable and placed the function inline on the change event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#officeSearch, #specialtySearch").on('change',
        function () {
            var selectedOffice = $('#officeSearch').val();
            var selectedSpecialty = $('#specialtySearch').val();
            var allPersons = $("#filterList .profile");
            var filter = "";
            if (selectedOffice != "all") {
                filter = '[data-office="' + selectedOffice + '"]'
            }
            if (selectedSpecialty != "all") {
                filter += '[data-specialty="' + selectedSpecialty + '"]'
            }
            var $matching = allPersons.filter(filter);
            $(allPersons).not($matching).removeClass('out').fadeOut(500);
            $matching.removeClass('out').fadeIn(500);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. Try something like this....

```
var match = function(office, specialty, profile) {
    var show = ((office == 'all' || office == $(profile).data('office')) &&
               (specialty == 'all' || specialty == $(profile).data('specialty')));

    if (show && !$(profile).is(':visible')) {
        $(profile).fadeIn();
    }

    if (!show && $(profile).is(':visible')) {
        $(profile).fadeOut();
    }
}

var filter = function() {
    var selectedOffice = $('#officeSearch').val();
    var selectedSpecialty = $('#specialtySearch').val();

    $.each($('#filterList .profile'), function(i, profile) {
        match(selectedOffice, selectedSpecialty, profile);
    });
};

$("#officeSearch").on('change', function(){
    filter();
});
$("#specialtySearch").on('change', function(){
    filter();
});
```

working fiddle here.... http://jsfiddle.net/6Q8FF/

Comment: I think the asker wants an AND match. If you select  `Communication` AND `Bone cancer` you should get no matches, but yours gives `Person C`

Comment: That's correct. You shouldn't get Person C if you select Communication and Bone cancer because person C is in the office of Internal Medicine.

Comment: thanks, @TrueBlueAussie.  Bad parenthesis on the setting of the show variable.  Fixed here... http://jsfiddle.net/6Q8FF/1/

Comment: Thanks so much @Trent I'm going to dig through this so to ensure I understand it. From the looks of it though, it looks like it's what I was trying to achieve!